# Add artifact to local repository from project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is there a way add artifact to local maven repository from my eclipse project?

currently i have a project that contain many jars, and i have started using maven. what i need is to add all these jars to the local repository in an automated way without redownload them or adding them one by one and specifying their coordinates.

Comment: Create a pom file containing the dependencies you need, and build your project with Maven. This will download the dependencies and store them in your local maven repo, with their own pom and transitive dependencies. You shouldn't install anything into your local repo, unless it doesn't exist in any public or company repository.

Comment: @JB Nizet read the question carefully i have about 200m jar files in my projects , do you expect me to add every jar as dependencies , it will take a weak. is there a way to create the pom file from the project??

Comment: 200 million jar files used by a single project? That doesn't make any sense. I doubt there even exist 200 million jar files in Maven central. If you meant 200 jar files, it's already a huge (too big) number, but there's a good chance that 4/5 or 9/10 of them are transitive dependencies of top-level dependencies. And adding 20 or 40 top-level dependencies in a pom shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: m mean megabyte. Thanks for the morale i will start adding them, it seems there is no other , and sorry if i was rude @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

Make a new Maven project in Eclipse, and add all your code to the src/main directory. Now you will have lots of compile errors, because of missing dependencies.

Now start auto adding the dependencies. In Intellj you can add something using alt-enter, which also has the option to "add maven dependency". This adds that dependency from the maven repository to the pom. I do not know eclipse well enough, but it probably also has this feature.

Now, in a normal project, you will find most of your required dependencies somewhere in Maven Central. If you miss any, you can add them using manual installation to your local repository, as suggested by Manas Mukherjee

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={jar_file_name_path}.jar -DgroupId={groupId} 
-DartifactId={artifactId} -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a script using mvn install command.

mvn install:install-file -Dfile={jar_file_name_path}.jar -DgroupId={groupId} 
-DartifactId={artifactId} -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar

You can add all dependencies in pom file as well

Thanks

Comment: i need a way to auto add the dependency to the pom file from the jar(project). it seem there no such thing so i have to add each jar as a depedency